# Show Element Not Working : On Specfic Site

Tags: javascript, css

I am confused.  This exact CSS works on other sites and same browser.
But on a certain website.  The drop down does not work?

Is there a Heading Setter or something? Website setting?  Its confusing me.

```
 <button onclick="javascript:showElement('bshd')" style="padding:2px;"> Button </button>
 <div id="bshd" style="display:none;"> 
 This Should Show Now
 </div>
```

Comment: Can you provide images showing the element appearing correctly and incorrectly? Can you provide information about the browsers used? What do you mean by "other sites" - other domain names? Or other urls on the same domain? This question needs a lot more info!

Comment: Did you try using `visibility: hidden;` and `visibility: visible`? Also, I don't think javascript:showElement() is valid code.

Comment: Browser is Mozilla Firefox - I have used that same code for years.  Visibility Hidden does not work. Code works fine elswhere other than the site I'm currently working on.  I'll start a test page and start adding components.  Must be an HTML/Header thing?

Comment: You've never needed `javascript:` before a function in an `onclick` attribute, only in an `href` attribute on an anchor.

Answer (score -1):

I get that this showElement fucntion is custom made by you? You can achieve the same thing by using jquery show() function:

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<button onclick="$('#bshd').show()" style="padding:2px;"> Button </button>
 <div id="bshd" style="display:none;"> 
 This Should Show Now
 </div>
```